# using matrix as a population in ga function of Matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to use genetic algorithm in matlab. I have a matrix as a population.
how can I use a specific matrix as a population to input in ga function of Matlab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [`gaoptimset`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/gaoptimset.html) setting the `'InitialPopulation'` field and pass the result to your `ga` as the `options` argument

example:

```
pop = {rand(n,m)} %// The {} might not be necessary.
options = gaoptimset('InitialPopulation',pop);
x = ga(....., options)
```

Comment: can you give me a simple example pls?

Comment: @jacob see my example. Can't make it any clearer than that

Comment: thx, I am completing my scenario using your example.

Comment: I have set Generations to 1, but the algorithm doesn't stops after first iteration. 
options = gaoptimset('InitialPopulation', pop, 'Generation' , 1);
x = ga(@fitnessFunction, 24, [],[],[],[],[],[],[], options)

Comment: @jacob Please mark this solution as correct. I suggest that you ask your new question about the generations as a **new question**, but I suggest you give far more information this time, more code etc or people won't be able to solve such a specific problem for you.